# Help identify this part

Tags: diodes, identification

Someone asked about this part, and I was pretty sure it was a TVS diode from Vishay, but pictures at Mouser and elsewhere say I'm probably wrong (or that my memory is from parts of a decade or two ago). But the shape is pretty distinctive, so I figured someone here might recognize it. [image]

Comment: Gas discharge tube?

Comment: looks to be some form of axial lead capacitor. I don't know I'm just guessing by the way it has something that looks like a C.

Comment: Further searching suggests it's a motorola diode, possibly MR751, not manufactured for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Further searching suggests it's a motorola diode, possibly MR751, not manufactured for a while now.